# Given two lists, return the minimal number of changes needed for one list to become the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given two lists with the same length:

```
a = [15, 10, 15, 14]

b = [14, 15, 14, 14]
```

What is the minimal number of changes needed for 'a' to become 'b'?

This is my attempt at it:

```
c3=0
fht2= [15, 10, 15, 14]
sht2= [14, 15, 14, 14]

for i in range(0,len(fht2)):
  for j in range(0,len(sht2)):
    if fht2==sht2:
      c=0
    else:
      if fht2!=sht2:
        if fht2[i]!=sht2[j] and fht2[i]<=sht2[j]:
          fht2[i]+=abs(fht2[i]-sht2[j])
          c3+=1 
        
        
        if fht2[i]!=sht2[j] and fht2[i]>=sht2[j]:
          fht2[i]-=abs(fht2[i]-sht2[j])
          c3+=1 
print(fht2)          
print(c3)
```

The output should be:

```
[14, 15, 14, 14]
3
```

However, my output is :

```
[14, 14, 14, 14]
11
```

Please assist.

Comment: What counts as a change?

Comment: count need to 3 but my count is 11

Comment: Are the lists always the same length?

Comment: From what I can understand, you just need to count the number of times a[i] != b[i], I am assuming a and b are of same length otherwise you can never make a and b same

Comment: yes bro list always have same length

Comment: What do you mean by *'What is the minimal number of **changes** needed'* ? There could be an arbitrary no.of rules. Define / describe it precisely.

Comment: Does the order of the elements also have to be the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Ezio I have dropped an answer based on your comment

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [15, 10, 15, 14]

b = [14, 15, 14, 14]

list_length = len(a)
print("list length:",list_length)
counter = 0
for i in range(list_length):
    if a[i]!= b[i]:
     counter = counter + 1 

print ("minimal number of changes is:",counter)
```

Output:

> list length:4

> minimal number of changes is: 3

Please learn to write a better question